# Xcode: Objective-C: Type mismatch

Tags: objective-c, xcode, enums, typedef, type-mismatch

The product build succeeds, but the test fails. How do I pass the type-mismatch failure reported on the line with `STAssertEquals` below?

```
// TransactionSpec.m

#import "Transaction.h"

@interface TransactionSpec : SenTestCase
@end

@implementation TransactionSpec

#pragma mark Properties

- (void)testProperties {
    Transaction *transaction = [[Transaction alloc] init];
    transaction.type = TransactionTypePay;

    STAssertNotNil(transaction, @"transaction exists");
    STAssertEquals(transaction.type, TransactionTypePay, @"type property works"); // Type mismatch
}

@end

// Transaction.h

typedef enum {
    TransactionTypePay,
    TransactionTypeCharge
} TransactionType;

@interface Transaction : NSObject

@property (nonatomic) TransactionType *type;

@end

// Transaction.m

#import "Transaction.h"

@implementation Transaction

@synthesize type;

@end
```

Answer (score 3):

Your `type` property is a *pointer* to a `TransactionType` (which is probably not intended) while `TransactionTypePay` is an actual `TransactionType`.

Answer (score 2):

Your `type` property is declared as a **pointer** to enum, which probably should not be so

Comment: How should it be declared? I just followed [`<UIKit/UITableView.h>`](https://github.com/enormego/UIKit/blob/af0df999735b29259b2a64342d616bc04bce54de/UITableView.h#L15-18).

Answer (score 1):

Casting `transaction.type` to `TransactionType` fixes the issue:

```
STAssertEquals((TransactionType)transaction.type, TransactionTypePay, @"type property works");
```

But, why should I have to do that since I declare:

```
@property (nonatomic) TransactionType *type;
```

Comment: Oops. Take out the asterisk (*) before `type`. Then, you won't have to cast it.